# javascript doesn't work in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

JavaScript:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if  ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
        $('#footer').show();
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
#footer {
    display: none;
}
```

This is supposed to reveal a hidden `div` at the bottom of a page when scrolled all of the way down to the bottom. For some reason, the hidden `div` never gets shown in Firefox. Is there another method using jQuery to create the same effect?

EDIT: Here's the page where it's not working correctly in Firefox

http://safe.tumblr.com/theme/preview/34069

Comment: Is there more than one element with ID #footer in your document?

Comment: The show function would obviously work. Can you debug and check the values in the if statement?

Comment: What's the point of hiding something which is already not visible until you scroll down to it?

Comment: No, but #footer comes up in the css twice - the second time it's wrapped in a block that will either include it or not based on the user's settings.

Comment: Jamie - the footer is fixed at the bottom of the window

Comment: You can try >= instead of ==, not sure if it's the problem.

Comment: Posting a working link to the page or posting an example on jsFiddle would really help

Comment: Works for me in FF 11: http://jsfiddle.net/CD3Vd/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a small difference between the max value for scrollTop and what documentHeight - windowHeight gives you, so I would propose to subtract a small safety factor:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 3) {
        $('#footer').show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to be using this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
       $('#footer').show();
   }
});
```

Comment: Where is the difference to his expression?

Comment: == instead of - following $(window).height()

Comment: Yeah but how is that different from the original approach? The math seems to be exactly the same...

Comment: Not sure - but since it's specifically Firefox where the problem occurs, I believe something like this could be the cause. I ultimately want a solution that works everywhere, because I highly doubt this even works at all in IE.

Comment: Did you try it and it worked? That would be a really strange behavior!